# access methods of model attributes in JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, el

I'm using Spring MVC, and I was wondering if it's possible to use methods of an object added to the model in the view (JSP).I was trying to do so with this code:

```
<form id="formDetail" action="${detailForm.generateURLDetail()}" ...
```

The object is accessible in the view (I can use its attributes), but I'm not allowed to use methods. I haven't seen nothing in Spring docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use getter notation, or create a [custom function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaio) (required if the method takes parameters).

Or, since you already know you need it, execute the function in the controller and expose the resulting value in the model--there's no need to call it in the JSP itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in EL by renaming your method `generateURLDetail()` to `getUrlDetail()` then  change your form to;

```
<form id="formDetail" action="${detailForm.urlDetail}"
```

Note that you cannot pass parameters to methods in EL.

Comment: That's no longer true, really.